# Returning position of specific symbol in list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, position, symbols

For this function I'm writing I want to return the position of a specific character that is closest to the top left of the list of lists. It'd be great to accomplish this in the most basic way without importing modules. Here is the code I have so far then I will explain more about what I'm trying to do

```
def find_position(symbol,lst): 

# Sample List: [['.','M','M','G','G'],
#               ['.','.','.','.','h'],  
#               ['B','B','B','.','h']]
#
    for sublist in lst:
        for symbol in sublist:
            if symbol == True:
            lst.find(symbol)
        return symbol
            else: 
            return None
```

So if the function was instructed to find '.' then it should return (0,0) since it is in the first position of the first list. If the function was told to find 'h' then it should return (1,4) since it is in the 4th position (python starts from 0) of the second list. My current code doesn't look for the character closest to the top left as I'm not sure how to program that. Thanks in advance for any help I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel's way is a bit faster in time execution but this also works for comparison:

```
def find_pos(listname, symbol):
    for i in range(len(listname)):
        for j in listname[i]:
            if j == symbol:
                return i ,listname[i].index(j)
```

Comment: Thanks, does your code return the position in parenthesis? For some reason when I run your code it returns None for the position instead of the position

Comment: It does. Did you correctly type in the function execution? For example if the name of your list was "mylist" it would be   find_pos(mylist, ".")

Comment: You're right there was a problem on my end now it is working perfectly. I decided to give you best answer as this was closer to my original code

Comment: If all you needed was parenthesis, edit Daniels code at the return statement to:   return ("({},{})".format(index,i))   basically adding them around the format code, the time of execution for larger needs would eventually show a real difference

Answer (score 1):

A function that iterates through all elements until it finds the character. As soon as it finds it, it returns the position. To find the psotion you can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) fucntion which returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over sequence

```
def find_position(symbol,lst):
    for index, my_list in enumerate(s):
        for i,item in enumerate(my_list):
            if symbol == item:
                return "{},{}".format(index,i)
    return "Not found"    

s = [['.','M','M','G','G'],
              ['.','.','.','.','h'],  
              ['B','B','B','.','h']]
a =  find_position("h",s)
```

Comment: Thanks what are the values of s and my_list when enumerating? I'm not sure what is being enumerated. Your code works well I'm wondering so I can understand how it works